# Huge String Table in Java

Tags: java, string

I've got a question about storing huge amount of Strings in application memory. I need to load from file and store about 5 millions lines, each of them max 255 chars (urls), but mostly ~50. From time to time i'll need to search one of them. Is it possible to do this app runnable on ~1GB of RAM?

Will

```
ArrayList <String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
```

work?

As far as I know String in java is coded in UTF-8, what gives me huge memory use. Is it possible to make such array with String coded in ANSI?

This is console application run with parameters:

```
java -Xmx1024M -Xms1024M -jar "PServer.jar" nogui
```

Comment: Why not database?

Comment: UTF-8 encoded strings use exactly as much memory as ASCII strings if all you use is ASCII characters (which seems given if the strings are URLs), so UTF-8 encoding wouldn't be a problem. But IIRC, Java uses Utf-16 internally, which indeed uses twice as much memory in general.

Comment: You should at least provide an initial size to the ArrayList to avoid hundreds of Array copy operations during initialization, e.g.: `new ArrayList<String>(1000 * 1000);`

Comment: The second part is about searching through them. You probably want to use a `SortedSet` or some such quickly searchable collection.

Comment: Other tip, use `intern()` if you know strings are repeated, as this holds only one copy of each unique string in the JVM. This add an overhead (CPU) but saves memory.

Comment: And if you are able to `intern()` then use `IdentityHashMap`. The intern code probably finds a stringer faster in its pool then `SortedSet`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The latest JVMs support `-XX:+UseCompressedStrings` by default which stores strings which only use ASCII as a byte[] internally.

Having several GB of text in a List isn't a problem, but it can take a while to load from disk (many seconds)

If the average URL is 50 chars which are ASCII, with 32 bytes of overhead per String, 5 M entries could use about 400 MB which isn't much for a modern PC or server.

Comment: +1 for teaching me about `UseCompressedStrings`. Are there any downsides to using it?

Comment: I load it only at app start, and save it in background Thread. Thx for answer

Answer (score 2):

A Java String is a full blown object. This means that appart from the characters of the string theirselves, there is other information to store in it (a pointer to the class of the object, a counter with the number of pointers pointing to it, and some other infrastructure data). So **an empty String already takes 45 bytes** in memory (as you can see [here](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/memory/string_memory_usage.shtml)).
Now you just have to add the maximum lenght of your string and make some easy calculations to get the maximum memory of that list.

Anyway, I would suggest you to load the string as **byte[]** if you have memory issues. That way you can control the encoding and you can still do searchs.

Comment: `byte[]` would kill the search?

Answer (score 1):

Is there some reason you need to restrict it to 1G? If you want to search through them, you definitely don't want to swap to disk, but if the machine has more memory it makes sense to go higher then 1G.

If you have to search, use a `SortedSet`, not an `ArrayList`